# Unable to UNINSTALL ORACLE VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

For Updateing WINDOWS 22H2 I need to uninstall Oracle VM VirtualBox. I did all mentioned [here](https://ugetfix.com/ask/fix-cant-update-windows-10-because-virtualbox-needs-to-be-uninstalled/) and I also have tried 3rd party de-installer like [Reno Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/preview-log/?pid=5781&pname=Oracle%20VM%20VirtualBox) but without Success. Always this info Screen comes up: [image: VirtualBox needs to be uninstalled]. I think there are more other programs which creates an VM from Oracle like Android Studio etc. Has any one an idea what I could do furthermore.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I  have found the reason:

1. I used  [Fortect](https://ugetfix.com/fortect/download/) and let ceaned my system
2. I found after scanning the whole HDD for VirtualBOX that `LINUX LIVE USB Creator` does also use and create a VirtualBox. After De-Installing this Program Files by the uninstaller I could install the updates.